# DCDevice not working on macOS. `com.apple.devicecheckd` was invalidated

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to use `DCDevice` to get a token.

```swift
let isSupported = DCDevice.current.isSupported
```

If I simply try to get the `isSupported` flag. It will display on the logs the following messages.

```
2020-10-10 12:23:08.828292-0300 taskfy[91547:5487907] [core] XPCConnection failed with error: 
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 
"The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.devicecheckd was invalidated." 
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.devicecheckd 
was invalidated.}
2020-10-10 12:23:08.828396-0300 taskfy[91547:5487907] [core] isSupported error: 
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named
com.apple.devicecheckd was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to 
service on pid 0 named com.apple.devicecheckd was invalidated.}
```

This leads me to think that the problem is not because the `DCDevice` is not supported by the current device. But, instead, it had some kind of problem with some expected running process in the computer.

Comment: Hi Amadeu, since the error code 4099 in relation with XPCConnecion is related to many networking errors, I would like to ask you if you can provide more information on the code that you're running. The line of code in your question doesn't give me any handles to work with.